# How to upload a file on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I created a Repository, but I want to upload my project to it.

I've looked on the repository page for an upload button of some kind but I haven't seen anything of the sort.

I've looked at the links provided so far but I'm still getting nowhere.

They mention command line, is that Windows command line ?

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps. Hope you have already configured [`git`](https://git-scm.com/downloads) in your local environment.

1) First Create a project in GitLab

[image]

2) After you created a project in next page you could see something like below image. And follow the instructions that I have highlighted with red color. I think your are working on Windows OS machine, so use Windows command line to do that.

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: @Tien Ho glad to hear that :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use windows command prompt but before you have to install GitHub software for your PC. Go to GitHub official website. **Download** and **install** it. 
After installing it you can also use their **Git Bash** Command Prompt for command or you can use **Git GUI** without command.
Another easy process is to go to GitHub. ***Login*** then ***Create a Repository*** and then upload your files in ***import project***.